# How about awarding a badge for consistently asking zero-score questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges, badge-request

Suppose there is a question with lot of upvoted answers and comments. This question even can be marked as favourite. But the question itself neither upvoted nor downvoted for a long time.

Do we have a special badge for such questions? On one hand, this question attracts some attention, generates upvotes and discussion. On the other hand, the question itself is, well, don't know, dull may be :) Quite rare and noteworthy situation. Or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why would we award a badge for this? Badges exist to encourage *positive* and *desirable* behavior. As the tag wiki for the [badge](/questions/tagged/badge) tag says:

> Badges are awarded to encourage and incentivize positive community actions within the site.

If you ask a question that has received 0 upvotes, that's not exactly positive behavior: clearly, no one found your question useful or interesting. The situation you describe may indeed be rare, but it's not noteworthy, at least not in a good way or one that we want to regularly encourage. Remember that good questions are *not* intended to attract "discussion".

The fact that your question still attracted helpful answers (as indicated by the upvotes that those answers have received) is a testament to those individual answerers—*not your question*. We already reward them with reputation and badges for their answers.

If you've asked this many questions with 0 upvotes, you should be thanking your lucky stars that you haven't received any downvotes, which *do* cost you reputation.

Comment: I was not talking about myself, by the way ) Imagine an interesting question which is, for example downvoted. You upvote it, some other guys also, and it once again zero. Is this zero identical to that one which was zero from the beginning?

Comment: @Cody: Well, you could always put it in a group with Tumbleweed. But I guess that one's going to stay the only exception.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, Tumbleweed is an exception because it's sort of a "consolation prize". In the situation described here, the person who asked the question still got a good answer (or two or five). They don't need any extra rewards for asking an "average" question.

Comment: @shabunc: I didn't mean to imply that you had asked the question. Read the word "you" in my answer as the royal You, referring to any individual in this situation. And yes, the +1/-1 zero is close enough. Why would that be any different? You get +5 for the upvote, -2 for the downvote, so you're still up 3 in terms of reputation anyway.

Comment: @Cody: I completely agree with you; just wanted to point out the one exception to your 2nd sentence.

Comment: @Cody, ok, I guess this it the answer. But as for me, there is a difference between questions which are close to zero just because they are, or a question, say, with -10 downvotes and 10 upvotes.

Comment: @shabunc: Yes, there's a difference of +30 reputation. There might be an argument for a "controversial question" badge here on Meta, but definitely not on Stack Overflow. Getting the same (or similar) number of downvotes to upvotes is a **sure sign of a problematic question**, not a desirable phenomenon.

Comment: I can see why this is not desirable, I just can not understand why this is bad. If N people believe this is interesting and N people disagree, it's a complex question.

Comment: @Cody : Unsung Hero : Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.  Don't see the positive behaviour here. Apart from the fact that people don't bother to upvote your answer as they don't find it helpful.

Comment: @Cody : Tumbleweed - Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

Comment: @Joris: Well, remember that the answers were *accepted* by the person who asked the question, which indicates that they found them helpful. If there were multiple answers to the question, they were the *most* helpful out of all of those provided. (See discussion on the Tumbleweed badge above.)

Comment: @shabunc: No, a complex question should not get downvoted. A *bad* question gets downvoted. One that shows no research effort, and is unclear or unhelpful. Check the tooltip on the downvote arrow.

Comment: You are talking about situation when the question has been mainly downvoted - why do you ignore the theoretical situation when the same amount of people find question interesting. Check the tooltip on the upvote arrow )))

Comment: By the way, this very question it definitely not balanced to zero )))

Comment: @shabunc: Uh, somehow I'm not being clear here. See my previous comment: "Getting the same (or similar) number of downvotes to upvotes is a **sure sign of a problematic question**, not a desirable phenomenon." A good question should *not* get the same number of downvotes as upvotes. Meta is different than the main site, but we're not talking about Meta here.

Comment: You are axiomatizing that such question is problematic one **by definition**. It can be so (probably it is, actually), but I'm not sure for 100 percents. Flame questions are just voted to be close, for example.

Comment: @shabunc: Lots of people downvote them first before voting to close. And lots of people without close vote privileges downvote them. Yes, **by definition** a good question should not receive an equal number of upvotes as downvotes. Downvotes have a specific meaning on the main site. Please don't confuse them with "disagreement votes" like they are here on Meta.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's good I've asked this question. At least, now I know more about the conceptual difference of meta and "pure" stack

Comment: @shabunc: The [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) explains the difference quite well...

Comment: It seems zero votes on questions with a few answers is something I specialize in but making this a badge is a little silly.